# Change scoop folder in user - grunt and gulp not working

Tags: windows, npm, gulp, gruntjs

Hi: I've used scoop to install node and then gulp and grunt;
Now I'd want to change the \scoop\ folder from my current user folder

C:\users\mycurrentuserfolder\scoop
to
C:\user\anotheruserfolder\scoop

- I already migrated all the folders inside scoop
- I looked for the occurrences of "mycurrentuserfolder" inside text files in the scoop folders and replaced it with "anotheruserfolder"
- I've already added all the Windows' User variables
- modified the "current" junction links inside the scoop folders
- I performed

  npm install -g grunt-cli gulp-cli --force

But alas both grunt and gulp seems not recognized (seems a missing path problem).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try running `scoop reset nodejs` (or `scoop reset *` to fix all apps).
This should fix add `%PATH%` to `nodejs\current\bin` where grunt and gulp should be located.